# How to update Homebrew SHA256?

Tags: homebrew, sha

This seems like a very noob question but I can't find an answer anywhere!

I'm very new to developing packages for Homebrew but when I edit my formula and come to update my package I get the following error

```
Error: SHA256 mismatch
```

My question is, how do I generate the expected SHA256 value?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After editing the formula, you can run `brew fetch your-formula --build-from-source` to fetch the tarball and display the new checksum. If you've already downloaded the tarball somewhere, you can calculate the hash with `openssl sha256 < some_tarball.tar.gz` or `shasum -a 256 some_tarball.tar.gz`.

Comment: How would I know that the tarball I downloaded wasn't corrupted? Isn't the only way to know for sure is by having the package maintainer provide the SHA256 themselves? For example, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli only provides an MD5. Is it expected I verify my download matches the MD5, and then I generate the SHA256?

Answer (score 0):

For casks, I prefer to change the cask sha256 to something wrong and then run `brew cask fetch {caskName}`, which then throws an error that shows the "Actual" sha256 for the downloaded file. You can just copy and paste that.